# Rename multiple new sheets with names from list

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I have a macro that creates multiple sheets of data from a list of URLs in the first sheet of the workbook. Currently the sheets are named numerically, 1-12 (as I have 12 urls creating sheets). What I owuld like to do is give each new sheet the name from the cell adjacent to the cell with the url in sheet 1.

I would also like to assing the name that the sheets has been given to its own A1 cell.

The URLs are located in cells A1:A12, the names are located in B1:B12.

Here is a copy of the macro...

```
Sub scrape()
    Dim mystr As String

    For Each ws In Sheets
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        If ws.Name <> "EDM" Then ws.Delete
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    For x = 1 To 12
        Worksheets("EDM").Select
        Worksheets("EDM").Activate
        mystr = "url;http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id=8475791"
        mystr = Cells(x, 1)
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x

        ' Macro1 Macro
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
                                         mystr, Destination:=Range("$B$2"))
            '.CommandType = 0
            .Name = "player.htm?id=8475791"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebTables = "4"
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

[image]

Code:

```
Sub go()
    ' variables "ws" and "last" will refer to sheets. 
    Dim ws, last As Worksheet
    Dim r, c As Range
    ' This range is the list of NAMES, in this case in column B
    Set r = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B1:B3")

    ' We step over each cell in the list of names
    For Each c In r
        ' The cell contents contain the new sheet name
        Name = c.Value
        ' We determine which sheet is currently the last sheet
        Set last = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        ' We add a new sheet, placing it after the last sheet
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=last)
        ' Set the name of the new sheet
        ws.Name = Name
        ' Inside the new sheet, write our NAME into cell "A1"
        ws.Range("A1").Value = Name
    Next c
End Sub
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: That code works to create new sheets with those names, but my inexperience leads me astray in knowing how to combine it with my original code. Any more help you can provied would be killer!

Comment: I realize this may seem quite simple to most but I'm working off only what uncle google can teach me. I'm trying my best to find a solution on my own but I'm struggling!

Comment: I have added comments to the code. If it is still unclear, you will have to be very specific about which part is causing difficulty.  Do you understand what your code is doing? Have you stepped through your code at run-time? The VBA debugger is pretty good, you can inspect the values of all the variables while debugging.

Comment: The biggest problem is that I'm in (sadly) way over my head. I'm trying to do something that I know can be done, but don't have enough basic knowledge of the language and functions. I'll give it a go and see what happens. Thanks so much for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use offset(x,y) to get a cell from another cell. You can then get a specific cell in a workbook by using Range("A1").offset(x,y).

Your code should work fine, as long as you replace:

```
mystr = "url;http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id=8475791"
 'mystr As String
mystr = Cells(x, 1)
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.count)).Name = x
```

With these lines:

```
mystr = "url;" & Range("A1").offset(x, 0).Value
myname = Range("A1").offset(x, 1).Value
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myname
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Sub AddSheets()
Dim element As Variant, aURLs() As Variant, aNames() As Variant
Dim wsName As String, i As Long

 'aURLs() = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("URLs"))
 'aNames() = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("Names"))
aURLs() = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)))
aNames() = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)))

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For i = LBound(aURLs) To UBound(aURLs)
    If WorkSheetExists(CStr(aNames(i))) Then Worksheets(aNames(i)).Delete
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = aNames(i)
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2") = ActiveSheet.Name
    MyQuery CStr(aURLs(i)), CStr(aNames(i))
Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Sub MyQuery(urlString As String, nameString As String)
 'MsgBox urlString
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & urlString, _
    Destination:=Range("$B$1"))
    .Name = nameString
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "4"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub

 'WorkSheetExists in activeworkbook:
Function WorkSheetExists(aSheetName As String) As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet
On Error GoTo notExists
Set ws = Worksheets(aSheetName)
WorkSheetExists = True
Exit Function
notExists:
WorkSheetExists = False
End Function
```